# How to avoid heredoc expanding variables?

Tags: bash, escaping, substitution, heredoc

I'm trying to create a  script file using substitution string from ENV but want also to prevent some from escaping

```
export PLACEHOLDER1="myPlaceholder1Value"
sudo /bin/su -c "cat << EOF > /etc/init.d/my-script
#!/bin/bash

myvariable_1=toto$PLACEHOLDER1
myvariable_final=\"dynamicvar=\${myvariable_1},\${myvariable_2}\"
EOF
"
```

It results in which is not good as the **myvariable_final** are not escaped and substituted as the one from the init script dependencies ($remote_fs, $syslog, $network, $time)

```
#!/bin/bash

myvariable_1=totomyPlaceholder1Value
myvariable_2=titimyPlaceholder2Value
myvariable_final="dynamicvar=,"
```

---

If i try to put a backslash `\` behind the dollars `$`, I manage to avoid the substitution but I getting an unwanted backslash `\`:

```
export PLACEHOLDER1="myPlaceholder1Value"
export PLACEHOLDER2="myPlaceholder2Value"
sudo /bin/su -c "cat << EOF > /etc/init.d/my-script
#!/bin/bash

myvariable_1=toto$PLACEHOLDER1
myvariable_2=titi$PLACEHOLDER2
myvariable_final=\"dynamicvar=\$\{myvariable_1},\$\{myvariable_2}\"
EOF
"
```

results in:

```
#!/bin/bash

myvariable_1=totomyPlaceholder1Value
myvariable_2=titimyPlaceholder2Value
myvariable_final="dynamicvar=$\{myvariable_1},$\{myvariable_2}"
```

---

Wanted/attended result whould have been :

```
#!/bin/bash

myvariable_1=totomyPlaceholder1Value
myvariable_2=titimyPlaceholder2Value
myvariable_final="dynamicvar=${myvariable_1},${myvariable_2}"
```

solved by putting quote  around the **EOF** as below and using backslash to control the escaping when needed

```
export PLACEHOLDER1="myPlaceholder1Value"
export PLACEHOLDER2="myPlaceholder2Value"
sudo /bin/su -c "cat << 'EOF' > /etc/init.d/my-script
#!/bin/bash

myvariable_1=toto$PLACEHOLDER1
myvariable_2=titi$PLACEHOLDER2
myvariable_final=\"dynamicvar=\${myvariable_1},\${myvariable_2}\"
EOF
"
```

Comment: note that only the first 'EOF' need quotes!

Comment: if you use 'EOF' with quote, it would not replace, but for example in my case i need some variable to be replaced, and some env variables not to be escaped. how do we do that.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question as questions does not cover other user cases : anyway, check here : https://github.com/roboll/helmfile/issues/1640#issuecomment-1454786173

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Just use `'EOF'` to prevent the variable from expanding:

```
sudo /bin/su -c "cat << 'EOF' > /etc/init.d/my-script
#                       ^   ^
... contents go here
EOF
```

From `man bash`:

> **Here Documents**
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
> current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no
> trailing blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are
> then used as the standard input for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>       <<[-]word
>               here-document
>       delimiter
> ```
>
> No  parameter  expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion,
> or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any characters in word
> are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and
> the lines in  the  here-document are not expanded.  **If word is
> unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter
> expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion**.  In the
> latter case, the character sequence `\<newline>` is ignored,  and  `\`
> must  be used to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.

Comment: The quote around the 'EOF' did the trick as with escaping, I'm able to control what is replace and wnat is not replaced

Comment: Strangely inside a shell script when I do this (to create helper scripts), it doesn't recognize the closing `'EOF'`. It just includes the remainder of the parent script.

Comment: Finally I figured out what I was doing wrong. `'EOF'` should only be for the opening tag. NOT for the closing tag. Just use `EOF` without the quotes

Comment: @SridharSarnobat oh, interesting. Feel free to edit the answer to include this

Comment: If using with `sudo`, at the end should be a `EOF"` closing the parameter of `sh -c`. The problem with that is that it will silently remove any double quotes in the document.

Answer (score 6):

when using the su command put the command itself in sigle quotes and just escape the $ with a backslash. the placeholder variables has to set in command bash context (here after su). so you need to do sth like

```
su -c 'ph="ph"; cat << EOF > script 
varinscript=$ph
var=\${var}
EOF'
```

Comment: Your answer is fine but I want to prevent putting back all the env/export VAR into the command again.

Comment: so no need to quote EOF in that case?