# Running gitlab-ci pipeline jobs as non-root user

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a `mvn` project  which must be build as an non-root user
but by default gitlab-ci allows runners to run as root user.
I'm using `gitlab.com` runners by setting up `gitlab-ci.yml` file.
I tried creating a user and switching to it like this:

```
$ useradd ***
$ su -***
$ whoami
root
```

It still says I'm root.
How can I solve this?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187899/change-gitlab-ci-runner-user/40703269#40703269

Comment: @Alexander that does not solve , running non root user in the pipeline but rather deals with setting up non-root user in gitlab-ci runner

Answer (score 5):

You can easily achieve this with `sudo`, e.g.,
excerpt from my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
script:
    - useradd -d /builds/{GITLAB_USER} -g users -M -N builder
    - chown -R builder:users ..
    - |     
      sudo -H -i -u builder sh -e -x << EOS                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      umask 0077                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      export CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION_SYSTEM="gitlab" TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` DEFAULT_TARGET="debug"                                                                                                                                                      
      export PREFIX="\${HOME}/usr" SYSCONFDIR="\${HOME}/etc/conf" LOCALSTATEDIR="\${HOME}/var"                                                                                                                                                                 
      cd my-project                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      make install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      make -C _deploy/debian clean package bundle BUILD_ID="-0{other}\${TIMESTAMP}"                                                                                                                                                                        
      EOS
```

Where {GITLAB_USER} is your actual gitlab user.
Remember to escape $ in your script

Comment: In GitLab 10.0 and above, you can use `${GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}` instead of doing the username substitution manually - this makes it work across forks. You may also wish to replace the actual project name with `${CI_PROJECT_NAME}` (note you should not escape _this_ `$`), which makes it work across even forks that adopt a different project name.

Comment: Do note that you might want to quote `EOS` as `'EOS'` as per [How to avoid heredoc expanding variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920806/how-to-avoid-heredoc-expanding-variables), to avoid potentially confusing issues with variable expansion.

Comment: Tip: If you want to preserve the env use `--preserve-env=PATH` for using the same PATH. This is handy if you wanted to do a `sudo --preserve-env=PATH sh < EOS mvn build EOS` instead of a `sudo env "PATH=$PATH" mvn build`

Answer (score 0):

Just install the gitlab-runner service for the right user:

```
gitlab-runner install --working-directory /home/ubuntu --user ubuntu
```

Here, `ubuntu` is an arbitrary non-root user.

Comment: Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -user

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gitlab-runner install --working-directory /home/username --user username
```

You need to be root to install with the `--user` flag so you can run gitlab-runner as an unprivileged user.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I built a base image with Dockerfile that included allowing the new user to use sudo:

```
RUN yum makecache \
  && yum -y install shadow-utils sudo \
  && /usr/sbin/useradd -d /builds -g users -M -N builder \
  && echo 'builder ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

USER builder
```

Then fix the `/builds` permissions in the `before_script` section in the pipeline file: `.gitlab-cy.yml`

```
  before_script:
  - sudo /bin/chown -R builder:users /builds
  script:
  - ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I set up `gitlab-runner` for a non-root user inside a Vagrant VM (should work for non-VM machines as well):

- Check to see if the process is running for the existing user:

`ps aux | grep gitlab`

- If the process is running, it will look something like this after you run the previous command:

`/usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --config /etc/gitlab/runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner`

- Stop the existing `gitlab-runner` systemd service:

`sudo systemctl stop gitlab-runner`

- The process should no longer appear if you type `ps aux | grep gitlab` again.
- Uninstall the existing user's 'gitlab-runner' service:

`sudo gitlab-runner uninstall`

- Reinstall the service for the new user:

```
sudo gitlab-runner install \
  --service gitlab-runner \
  --user $USER \
  --working-directory /home/$USER
```

- Reload systemd daemons:

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

- Start the new user's `gitlab-runner` systemd service:

`sudo systemctl start gitlab-runner`

- To ensure the service runs on boot:

`sudo systemctl enable gitlab-runner`

- Check to see if the process is running for the new user:

`ps aux | grep gitlab`

- The new process should look something like this (I used Vagrant for this, so my user is `vagrant`):

`/usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /home/vagrant --config /home/vagrant/.config/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --user vagrant`

- Run `gitlab-runner` as your new user:

`gitlab-runner exec shell some_job`

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to accomplish this.
Since gitlab-ci jobs are simply docker containers running processes,
one way to achieve this
would be to use [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) where you can run a process as a non-root user.
Some links which show how to use gosu:

- [gosu with Jenkins](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/jenkins-docker)
- [How to use gosu](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/dna6/unning-docker-container-with-a-non-root-user-and-fixing-shared-volume-permissions-with-gosu)