# Behaviour of ftp 'put file*.txt' - Uploading the first matching file only

Tags: linux, ftp

Lets say there are two files in the working directory:

```
test201612290900.txt
test201612290901.txt
```

When I run

```
ftp -n $HOST <<SCRIPT
user $USER $PASSWORD
put test*.txt test.txt
bye
SCRIPT
```

with the `ftp` executable (linux), only **one** file gets put to the ftp site.

**EDIT**: I use this `*` because I don't now the exact filename in advance.

I found out it is always the first match (`test201612290900.txt`) that gets copied to the ftp site.

My **question**: is this documented behaviour? and, can I get control over this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `put` command uploads a single file only.

The pattern in your `put` command is actually resolved by a shell even before the `ftp` is executed (similarly to the environment variables like `$HOST`).

So this may answer your question:
[Does bash's * match files in alphanumeric order?](https://superuser.com/q/192280/213663)

---

Though note that syntax `put a b c` is wrong. It's even surprising it does not error out. So you cannot expect it to be documented.

You better do something like:

```
FILES=(test*.txt)
FILE=${FILES[0]}

ftp -n $HOST <<SCRIPT
user $USER $PASSWORD
put $FILE test.txt
bye
SCRIPT
```

Credits: [How can I get the first match from wildcard expansion?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156205/119732)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a here document without quoting.  This means that your shell will expand wildcards and interpolate variables in the here document before `ftp` even runs.

So in practice, you are sending

```
put test201612290900.txt test201612290901.txt test.txt
```

Quoting the here document solves that, but of course, that won't make your program work, because the FTP `put` command doesn't support wildcards.  As indicated in Ipor Sircer's answer, the `mput` command does; but again, you will need proper quoting around the here document, too.

Comment: what is a 'here document'?

Comment: So, if `put test201612290900.txt test201612290901.txt test.txt` is executed, what will that do? According to the docs this is the syntax: `put local-file [remote-file]`.

Comment: The behavior is probably undocumented and undefined.  Some clients will ignore the third argument, others will ignore the second, some will throw a syntax error, some will do something else.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code-in-shell/22698106#22698106 for how exactly to quote here documents.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing manpage of ftp is free today!

```
 mput local-files
             Expand wild cards in the list of local files given as argu‐
             ments and do a put for each file in the resulting list.  See
             glob for details of filename expansion.  Resulting file names
             will then be processed according to ntrans and nmap settings.
```

Comment: I'm not using `mput`, but `put`.

Comment: then use more put.

Comment: you mean multiple put commands? Well the issue is that I don't know the exact time component of the file.

Comment: then use one mput.

Comment: No, then it uploads all files. I don't want that.