# How create file via function using cat in Bash scenario

Tags: bash, function, variables, syntax, cat

I'm trying to create a function that allows me to send two variables to it.
My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function myfunc{
cat > file.xml << EOFcat
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
<source>
<vendor id='0x$1'/>
<product id='0x$2'/>
</source>
</hostdev>
EOFcat
}
trigger="191a:8003";
vID=$(lsusb | grep $trigger | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f3)
pID=$(lsusb | grep $trigger | cut -d ':' -f3 | cut -d ' ' -f1)
echo "vID=$vID"
echo "pID=$pID"
myfunc ($vID $pID);
```

send me an error:

```
./script3.bash: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `cat'
./script3.bash: line 3: `cat > file.xml << EOFcat'
```

If I'm not mistaken, that means I can't use 'cat' inside function.

So, the question arises: is it possible to write a function that will allow you to create an XML file with the passed parameters inside?

Comment: `cat << EOFcat >file.xml`

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: See `function` section in [Obsolete and deprecated syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).  Also, take a look at this related post: [Passing parameters to a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6212219/6862601).

Comment: `{` is only special when it is a single word; otherwise, it's an ordinary character that can appear in a function name. You are attempting to define a function named `myfunc{`. To see, try `function myfunc{ { echo hi; }`.

Comment: Also, take a look at [How to cat <<EOF >> a file containing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22697688/6862601) regarding heredoc, `<<`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even if available in bash, the `function` is not necessary and BTW is not standard

The declaration should probably be

```
myfunc () {
```

and call does not need them:

```
myfunc "$vID" "$pID"
```

Comment: Best of all, use the parentheses, and drop the non-standard keyword `function`.