# Better way of piping string into bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Currently, I have a script that adds lines into `.bashrc`. Here are a few of the lines. I feel this is not the most elegant way to do this. Is there a  better way?

```
echo 'echo -e "\033[1mhtop\033[0m \033[3m(Display dynamic real-time information about running processes)\033[0m"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
echo 'echo -e "\033[1mneofetch\033[0m \033[3m(CLI tool to display information about your operating system, software and hardware)\033[0m"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
echo 'echo -e "\033[1mnethogs =\033[0m eg; sudo nethogs \033[4meno1\033[0m \033[3m(Monitor bandwidth usage per process)\033[0m"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Note you are not piping, you are re-directing.

Comment: Maybe `motd` is something you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat <<EOF >>~/.bashrc
blabla
blabla
blablablalba
EOF
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation to your answer to assist future readers?

Comment: This is called the _heredoc format_ which tells _cat_ to read from the stdin stream until the specified _end is of stream marker is found. In our case the single word "EOF". @kennytm summarized it very nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2500451/1177024

Comment: Worked as expected. I added a back slash to `cat <<\EOF >>~/.bashrc` to avoid variable substitution as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code#answer-22698106)

Answer (score 0):

you can use brackets, to avoid copying the redirection.

```
{
   echo … &&
   echo … &&
   echo …
} >> ~/.bashrc
```

Note: the `/` is never needed after a `&&`.