# How to save a file using heredoc syntax but preserve the actual variable output?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, heredoc

cat test.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

#some other commands
#some other commands
loc="$(which chromium-browser)"
cat > loc.txt <<'endmsg'
location = '$loc'
endmsg
```

I have simplied my script to properly explain my issue.
I am trying to save the output of a variable in another file using heredoc .But it seems that heredoc simply saves the raw text present inside **endmsg** tags

**Currently**

cat loc.txt

```
location = '$loc'
```

Since "which chromium-browser" is actually - /usr/bin/chromium-browser

**Expectation**

cat loc.txt

```
location = /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

is there any way by which i could save the actual variable output in another file and not literally save the raw text.
Its fine its the answer doesn't uses heredoc for achieving this , although preferably it shouldn't be complex for doing something so simple.

Comment: See: [How to cat <<EOF >> a file containing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22697688/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus i tried changing the cat line like this referring to the accepted answer to add the bashslash - cat > loc.txt <<\endmsg , but still it saved the raw output. I don't want to use exact syntax from there because i am quite used to saving file like this , so tried making the minor change to my existing syntax

Comment: You should escape no part of the delimiter. No single quotes, double quotes, or backslashes.

Comment: You also don't want the single quotes within the here-doc, or you'll get `'location = /usr/bin/chromium-browser'`

Comment: thanks for pointing that typo out

Comment: You could use `printf '%s\n' "location - $(which chromium-browser)"`, no here-doc at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the single quotes:

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

#some other commands
#some other commands
loc="$(which chromium-browser)"
cat > loc.txt << endmsg
location = $loc
endmsg
```

will work fine.