# sql statement in shell being replaced by file names in pwd

Tags: shell, sqlplus

I have some embedded SQL in a ksh script with functionality to count the number of records in a table, however, the `select *` in the query is returning all file names

```
"$(sqlplus -s $username/$password@$hostname <<ENDOFSQL
            set head off
            select count(*) from (select * from table_a minus select * from table_b);
            exit;
ENDOFSQL)"
```

When I print the results of the query, I get `select count(*) from (select a.txt b.txt c.sql d.ctl`

What's going wrong here?

Comment: seems like you said it yourself - the shell is doing globbing - in which case quoting the query should avoid that. specifying what shell you're using might help, but this seems pretty general.

Comment: I think this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22697688/2422776

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cat <<EOF >> a file containing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code)