# bash echo is doing commands and not adding what I need

Tags: bash, echo

I need to create a new file name test.sh.
I need to write those lines with echo or somethings else but cant open new file manually and write it.
That is, I have to write down some things in the bash such a way that the following file is created:

```
TEST_VALUE=$1
if [[cat data | grep $TEST_VALUE]]; then
exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

But, when I do that by echo the result is:

```
TEST_VALUE=
if [[]]; then
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

I need the file as I write it with $1 and not the argument and with the grep.
I tried to grep each row but it is doing the command and not copied it as I want.
How do I do it?
Thank You

Comment: Can you post an example of the bash script that is generating this? Hard to say exactly what you're doing wrong without seeing it, but most likely you're not using quotes properly. See for example [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: As an aside, the generated file won't do what you want. You're probably looking for `if grep -q "$TEST_VALUE" data; then`

Comment: Sure,
this is the line that needs to go to tast.sh:
git bisect run ./test.sh $TEST_VALUE

Comment: I need to write in bash the line that is according to the lines above and will copy it to test.sh as I wrote it

Comment: I need to write in bash according to the lines above and it will copy it to test.sh as I wrote it –

Comment: `[[ ]]` will _never_ do what you're asking it to do, because that's not what it's meant for. It's syntax that provides an extended version of the `[` command, not part of `if` syntax.

Comment: You _could_ write, say, `[[ $(<data) = *"$TEST_VALUE"* ]]`, if that's what you intend.

Comment: Related: [How to `cat <<EOF` a file containing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code) -- the OP there has _half_ the solution, but only half so they hit the same problem the question here asks about.

Comment: (also, `[[` is syntax for extended shells like bash or ksh; if you don't put a shebang at the top of your script specifying an extended shell, it's not guaranteed it'll be available at all).

Comment: ...try running `if [[ 'false' ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi` -- you'll see it emits `true`, because the string `false`, _like any other non-empty string_, is truthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring that the content you're trying to copy is buggy, the best way to do this is with a *quoted heredoc*:

```
cat >file <<'EOF'
TEST_VALUE=$1
if [[cat data | grep $TEST_VALUE]]; then
exit 1
fi
exit 0
EOF
```

But that content **is** buggy! A better version would look like:

```
cat >file <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
test_value=$1
! grep -q -e "$test_value" <data
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'TEST_VALUE=$1 
if [[cat data | grep $TEST_VALUE]]; then
exit 1
fi
exit 0' > test.sh
```

You need to use quotes, in any other case your command will be executed.

Comment: One can (and should) use a quoted heredoc. The sample here falls down whenever one wants to use single quotes inside the value being copied.

Comment: It also can do badly on data containing backslashes, depending on exactly which version of `echo` is in use.

Comment: ...see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) for detailed guidance -- or just [the POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: and how do I copy the '' from the if [['cat data | grep $TEST_VALUE']]; then ?

Comment: @Try_hard, `if [[ 'anything' ]]` doesn't look at `anything` at a command, it just looks at it _as a string_ so it always returns true, no matter what `anything` would do if run as a shell command. This is part of why I told you that the command you're trying to run is buggy.

Comment: @Try_hard, ...that said, you can insert a literal single quote inside a single-quoted string using `'"'"'` -- the first `'` ends the prior single-quoted context, the following `"` enters a double-quoted context, the third character `'` is inside double quotes so it's literal, the fourth character `"` ends the double-quoted context, the fifth character `'` resumes a single-quoted context.